# What is the grenade priority?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

When throwing the last grenade of a type, It will automatically change to a new grenade type until you have no grenades of any type.

I imagine it doesn't pick at random. So what is the priority order to auto-select the next grenade type?

Comment: Now I'm curious and want to boot up the game, pick up nothing but grenades and throw them all! However from experience (I always equip the molotov when available), it seems to go to most lethal first, so molotov (already equipped), grenade, stun, smoke.

Comment: When you hit 'g' by default it goes to your grenade slot, whatever is equipped. When you click it again while a grenade is out you automatically try to swap to a frag first. If you have none a prompt will say 'no frag grenades available'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Personnal experience, it seems to be Frag>Molotov>Smoke>Stun

But can't find a source.

Comment: As in when you throw the last one of a type it cycles to the next type or starts at the top of the list? (ie. you throw your last smoke, does it auto equip frag grenade or stun grenade?)

Comment: It always starts from the top, pretty sure. When you finish a type, it's checks the list from the top, and picks the first it can find.

Comment: Coincidentally that order is also alphabetical order, which makes me think that it is probably just the default behaviour.